# How to catch the scroll offset RadListVIew in nativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I try getting scroll position, for infinity scroll (top)

```
<RadListView row="1" 
  [items]="_dataItems" 
  (scrolled)="onScrolled">

  onScrolled(scrollOffset) {
    this.scrollOffset = scrollOffset;
    console.log(this.scrollOffset); // undefined
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the Documentation / TypeScript declarations carefully.

With Angular you event binding should call the function with the `$event` object to get access to event arguments

```
<RadListView row="1" 
  [items]="_dataItems" 
  (scrolled)="onScrolled($event)">
```

Without above fix you event callback will never be called.

Secondly, what you receive in the event is type of `ListViewScrollEventData`.

```
onScrolled(event) {
   this.scrollOffset = event.scrollOffset;
   console.log(this.scrollOffset); // undefined
}
```